# What are the eigenfunctions and eigenvalues of a moebius strip?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, waves, eigenvalue, vibrations

A Moebius strip is a simple example of a non orientable surface.  Suppose a very thin metal model of one, say of length $2\pi L$ (midline), width a, thickness negligible is perturbed ("kicked"), and then left to freely vibrate transversely.   How do its vibrations differ compared to those of a simple cylinder of the same dimensions?   What about the eigenvalues, i.e. allowable frequencies?   (This is not a homework problem, but could be.)  For the free boundary case, what about torsional waves about the center longitudinal axis of the strip?   Naively, it feels like there should be a difference, i.e. doubling of wavelengths.      Is that right?

Comment: What boundary conditions do you have on the edge? One could certainly write some separable solutions for the free boundary case.

Comment: This does seem to be an exercise - you are looking for an answer which relates to $L, a$. According to the site policy you need to **show some effort** and also **ask about a conceptual difficulty**.

Comment: You've already asked the same question and received a good answer (which you accepted) on MathOverflow: https://mathoverflow.net/q/29175/98520

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the same question was asked and answered on MathOverflow.

Comment: You are right.  I do apologize.   Getting older, I guess.    Thanks to both answerers.    I don't know how to accept them both, but would be happy to.    -sg

Answer (score 2):

They would be some waves (obviously, so we may describe them by using complex exponentials)

$$\psi(x,y) = \exp i(l_xx + l_yy)$$

where x denotes the "periodic" coordinate and y the width of the band.

all that is left to do is to impose some boundary conditions onto the band. Let us say the the band has length $L$ (in the x direction) before it reconnects to itself. We must write

$$\psi(x,y) \sim \psi(x+L,y')$$

More specifically the image tells us that up becomes down and left becomes right after one revulsion such that the correct boundary conditions are:

$$\psi(x,y) = \psi(x+L,-y) \rightarrow \exp(2il_y y) = \exp(i l_x L) \forall y$$

At first sight I don't see any other solutions than $l_y = 0$ and $l_x = \frac{2\pi n_x}{L}$

**Conclusion**

If nobody finds a mistake in my reasoning I conclude that the topology of the mobius band eliminates oscillation along its y. Oscillations along the x direction do not pose any problem.

In fact this is consistent with intuition. Just grab a piece of paper and make a Mobius band from it. You will see that you cannot create any modes(= bends) in its y direction due to the boundary conditions !

*message to OP: thanks for the interesting question :)*

[image: Band]

Comment: I refined the question to specifically ask about possible doubling of the wavelength of lowest order torsional stationary waves in the free boundary case, or am I imagining that?

Comment: Why do you mean by torsional stationary waves ? Whatever they are shouldn't they be in my answer since it it the general wave solution ?

Answer (score 0):

I believe that they look something like this

[image]

In 2006 I was curious about the normal modes of graphene -- as sheets, ribbons, tubes, etc. I folded the structure of a narrow graphene nanoribbon into a mobius strip and gave it a "kick" of random velocities. These are the resulting disturbances that propagated around the ring in a molecular dynamics simulation.